# React native release signed apk file crashes after click on login button

Tags: android, react-native

I have created the APK file of my app using the below link.

```
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#docsNav
```

Successfully, It installed and once I click on the login button it shows "Unfortunately, the app has closed error". I tried creating APK of other project and it is working fine. But, in this project, it crashes.

Once after creating the project, I have changed my project name is the string.xml file. Is there any problem with that? Even tried to keep the previous name also, but my issue did not get resolved.
**My package.json file is**

```
{
  "name": "awsUpload",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.395.0",
    "link": "^0.1.5",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "^0.58.3",
    "react-native-aws3": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.26.2",
    "react-native-file-upload": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "uniqid": "^5.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.0.0",
    "jest": "24.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Is there any problem in my packages?

**My button file code is**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  Animated,
  Easing,
  Image,
  Alert,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {Actions, ActionConst} from 'react-native-router-flux';

import spinner from '../images/loading.gif';

const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const DEVICE_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const MARGIN = 40;

export default class ButtonSubmit extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
    };

    this.buttonAnimated = new Animated.Value(0);
    this.growAnimated = new Animated.Value(0);
    this._onPress = this._onPress.bind(this);
  }

  _onPress() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) return;

    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    Animated.timing(this.buttonAnimated, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 200,
      easing: Easing.linear,
    }).start();

    setTimeout(() => {
      this._onGrow();
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      Actions.secondScreen();
      this.setState({isLoading: false});
      this.buttonAnimated.setValue(0);
      this.growAnimated.setValue(0);
    }, 2300);
  }

  _onGrow() {
    Animated.timing(this.growAnimated, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 200,
      easing: Easing.linear,
    }).start();
  }

  render() {
    const changeWidth = this.buttonAnimated.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [DEVICE_WIDTH - MARGIN, MARGIN],
    });
    const changeScale = this.growAnimated.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [1, MARGIN],
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Animated.View style={{width: changeWidth}}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button}
            onPress={this._onPress}
            activeOpacity={1}>
            {this.state.isLoading ? (
              <Image source={spinner} style={styles.image} />
            ) : (
              <Text style={styles.text}>LOGIN</Text>
            )}
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Animated.View
            style={[styles.circle, {transform: [{scale: changeScale}]}]}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    top: -95,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    marginTop: 100,
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor : '#48a4ff',
    height: MARGIN,
    borderRadius: 20,
    zIndex: 100,
  },
  circle: {
    height: MARGIN,
    width: MARGIN,
    marginTop: -MARGIN,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'blue',
    borderRadius: 100,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    zIndex: 99,
    backgroundColor: '#48a4ff',
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',
  },
  image: {
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
  },
});
```

Comment: is the app running fine in debug mode?

Comment: Yes. Once I installed the app using react-native run-android command , it is perfectly fine and I checked the logs with run-android log-android . There are no errors. But in apk file I have .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem was not with my code**, I was using a set of code to access the device location, therefore it was failing in higher version of Android devices **due to security reason**.

I **solved** this by **referring below link**,

[How do I request permission for Android Device Location in React Native at run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822318/how-do-i-request-permission-for-android-device-location-in-react-native-at-run-t)