# React- Native .apk file failing in higher version of android devices

Tags: android, react-native

I have created .apk of my create the native project. It is working fine in android 5 and 6 version devices. It is failing in the higher version of the devices.

I have used below link to create the signed apk file.

```
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#docsNav
```

When I installed the react-native project in higher version of the devices using react-native run-android it is working fine. But , in case of .apk it is failing.

Can you help me to resolve this,

my package.json file is ,

```
{
  "name": "awsUpload",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.395.0",
    "link": "^0.1.5",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "^0.58.3",
    "react-native-aws3": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.26.2",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-file-upload": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-navigator": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-navigator": "0.0.0-0",
    "uniqid": "^5.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.0.0",
    "jest": "24.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

In logs, it is giving below error,

```
Failed to get property persist.sys.media.traces
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {e12e3b3} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fetching the device location using a set of codes. In the higher version of Android devices due to security reason, It was not allowing my app to fetch it. I add the android device permission by referring following link.

Link is,

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822318/how-do-i-request-permission-for-android-device-location-in-react-native-at-run-t
```