# Reack Native release .apk crashes in higher version of android devices with geolocation permission denied error

Tags: android, react-native

I have created a simple app which has a login page and when the user clicks on login button It navigates to another page. It works fine whenever I run my app using react-native run-android. But app crashes whenever I run the .apk file in a higher version of Android devices(it works fine in android 5 and 6).

package.json

```
{
    "name": "awsUpload",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "aws-sdk": "^2.395.0",
        "link": "^0.1.5",
        "react": "16.6.3",
        "react-native": "^0.58.3",
        "react-native-aws3": "0.0.8",
        "react-native-device-info": "^0.26.2",
        "react-native-file-upload": "^1.0.4",
        "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0",
        "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
        "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
        "uniqid": "^5.0.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-jest": "24.0.0",
        "jest": "24.0.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

I am using below code to get the geolocation. As I know, there is already an issue to get the geolocation in higher version of the Android device due to the protection and there is a solution in stack overflow. But I did not get it how to use it.

My code is ,

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component<Props> {

       constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

          currentLongitude: 'unknown',//Initial Longitude
          currentLatitude: 'unknown',//Initial Latitude

        }
      }
    componentDidMount = () => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          //Will give you the current location
           (position) => {
              const currentLongitude = JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude);
              //getting the Longitude from the location json
              const currentLatitude = JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude);
              //getting the Latitude from the location json
              this.setState({ currentLongitude:currentLongitude });
              //Setting state Longitude to re re-render the Longitude Text
              this.setState({ currentLatitude:currentLatitude });
              //Setting state Latitude to re re-render the Longitude Text
           },
           (error) => alert(error.message),
           { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
        );
        this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
          //Will give you the location on location change
            console.log(position);
            const currentLongitude = JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude);
            //getting the Longitude from the location json
            const currentLatitude = JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude);
            //getting the Latitude from the location json
           this.setState({ currentLongitude:currentLongitude });
           //Setting state Longitude to re re-render the Longitude Text
           this.setState({ currentLatitude:currentLatitude });
           //Setting state Latitude to re re-render the Longitude Text
        });
    }
   componentWillUnmount = () => {
      navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);

   }
    render() {
      return (
                <View>
                   <Text>Longitude: {this.state.currentLongitude}</Text>
                   <Text>Latitude: {this.state.currentLatitude}</Text>

                   {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
                </View> 
          );
        }
      }
```

Solution link is,

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865445/gps-location-provider-requires-access-fine-location-permission-for-android-6-0/33866959
```

Comment: Try to run in emulator of a higher version and see the log cat logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is completely clear, you need to get Permission for accessing location.

there are two types of permissions:

1- ones that can be granted just by adding permission to `manifest.xml`

2- ones that user, himself must accept that permission.(these usually shows within a `dialog` and asks user to give the app access to ... ).

Location permission is second type. so adding that permission to `Manifest.xml` won't do anything.

you can check the lists of permissions in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid

the way to ask user permission for that is explained in links below:

[How do I request permission for Android Device Location in React Native at run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822318/how-do-i-request-permission-for-android-device-location-in-react-native-at-run-t)

Comment: I found out that, my  .apk is crashing because I am getting the user location. How to solve this?

Comment: the info you are providing is not enough! plz give some code or stacktrace

Comment: and did you use android studio to debug?

Comment: I need to add that permission MainActivity.java file. I get confused about how to add that.

Comment: i edited my asnwer. if you are coding in react-native no need to go and write code in `MainActivity.java`, i hope it help you

Comment: what happened? could you fix your problem?

Comment: Thank you so much, Amas :). I have referred link and it is working completely fine.

Comment: Happy to hear that